# In Capybara, does :exact or Capybara.exact apply to have_selector?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm having difficulty using Capybara's `have_selector` when trying to match for an element where the text matches *exactly*.  I know that this can be done using a regular expression, but my reading of [Capybara's blog post](http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1) led me to believe that I could use an `:exact` arg or set `Capybara.exact = true`.  I am currently using Capybara 2.2.1.  Here is what I have:

Assuming that I have a page (called "test page").  On this page is this:

```html
<div id="my_div">abcdef</div>
```

I have a Cucumber feature test that looks like this:

```rb
Feature: Test for exact text matches in have_selector
Scenario:
  Given I am on the test page
  Then I should get a partial text match "bcde" in my div
  And I should get a partial text match "abcdef" in my div
  And I should get an exact text match using regexp "abcdef" in my div
  And I should not get an exact text match using regexp "bcde" in my div
  And I should get an exact text match using arg "abcdef" in my div
  And I should not get an exact text match using arg "bcde" in my div
```

My step definitions look like this:

```rb
Then /^I should get a partial text match "([^\"]*)" in my div$/ do |text|
  page.should have_selector('div#my_div', :text => text)
end

Then /^I should get an exact text match using regexp "([^\"]*)" in my div$/ do |text|
  page.should have_selector('div#my_div', :text => /^#{text}$/)
end

Then /^I should not get an exact text match using regexp "([^\"]*)" in my div$/ do |text|
  page.should_not have_selector('div#my_div', :text => /^#{text}$/)
end

Then /^I should get an exact text match using arg "([^\"]*)" in my div$/ do |text|
  page.should have_selector('div#my_div', :text => text, :exact => true)
end

Then /^I should not get an exact text match using arg "([^\"]*)" in my div$/ do |text|
  page.should_not have_selector('div#my_div', :text => text, :exact => true)
end
```

Contrary to my expectations, I got the following error:

```
And I should not get an exact text match using arg "bcde" in my div
expected not to find css "div#my_div" with text "bcde", found 1 match: "abcdef" (Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)
```

This leads me to believe that `:exact => true` is not doing anything in my `have_selector` call.  I have similarly tried to set `Capybara.exact = true` in my test setup configurations, but this also does not seem to affect my tests that I way I would have expected.

Am I missing something?  Or am I misunderstanding how this option is supposed to be used?  I know that I can always use the regular expression syntax for matching an exact text string, but I would have thought that the `:exact` option is specifically for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an open feature request, [Capybara Github Issue 1256](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1256), to have `have_selector` (and others) support exact text matching.

However, for now (in Capybara 2.x), the `:exact` option does not apply to the `:text` option. If I recall correctly, it is the following piece of code (from [query.rb](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/query.rb#L39-L42)) that does the text option filtering. As you can see, there is no logic or consideration of the `:exact` option.

```
def matches_filters?(node)
  if options[:text]
    regexp = options[:text].is_a?(Regexp) ? options[:text] : Regexp.escape(options[:text].to_s)
    return false if not node.text(visible).match(regexp)
  end
```

As per the [Capybara docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method), the `:exact` option is actually to:

> Control whether `is` expressions in the given XPath match exactly or
>   partially

This is basically only used in the [Capybara::Node::Actions](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions), where the text (or id, name, etc.) is not specified as an option - ex:

```
# Will match links that exactly match 'Password'
click_link('Password', :exact => true)

# Will match links that contain the word 'Password' - ex 'Password Confirmation'
click_link('Password', :exact => false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Capybara now has an `exact_text:` option that you can use:

```
page.should have_selector('div#my_div', exact_text: text)
```

You can also set it to be the default using `Capybara.exact_text = true`. [Docs here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders).